# Expected number of perfect matchings in bounded degree bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, probability-distributions, random-graphs, bipartite-graphs, perfect-matchings

Consider collection $\mathcal C_{n,n,\Delta}$ of every $2n$ vertex balanced bipartite graph of average degree $\Delta$.

What is the expected number of perfect matching a graph in $\mathcal C_{n,n,\Delta}$ have and what is the probability distribution?